# In SQL Server 2005 is there a way to set the default schema to anything other than dbo when the user has admin rights?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I am using SQL Server 2005 with Windows authentication.  My login has administrator rights.  For my login I have a user mapped to a database with the default schema set to "my_schema".  My login is not the owner of the database.  When I log on though, and try to execute a simple select statement on a table in "my_schema" without specifying the schema name, I get an invalid object error.  This does not happen when I log on as a user with no admin privileges.  What I think is happening is that SQL Server is changing the default schema to "dbo" because I have admin rights.  Is there a way to work around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sysadmin role members always get defaulted to dbo. It is a designed behaviour and cannot be overruled.

You are best off moving the user out of the Sysadmin role and back into the "normal" userspace

Comment: A more detailed answer with link to the official documentation can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3806301/806549

Answer (score -1):

You can set the default schema with the "DEFAULT_SCHEMA" option using either the CREATE USER or ALTER USER commands

```
CREATE USER exampleUser WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = exampleDB;
ALTER USER exampleUser WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = exampleDB;
```

Comment: I already set the default schema like this.  But it does not work when I have admin rights.

Comment: Sorry about that, I don't believe you can change the default schema as a member of "sysadmin" group.  It's generally considered bad practice to use a sysadmin as a general user, and creating an alternate general user circumvents your problem.

Comment: If you post code or XML, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code" button (101 010) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!