# What is the correct usage of zxjdbc to call stored procedures?

Tags: java, sql-server, stored-procedures, jdbc, jython

I am attempting to use zxJDBC to connect to a database running on SQL Server 2008 R2 (Express) and call a stored procedure, passing it a single parameter. I am using jython-standalone 2.5.3 and ideally do not want to have to install additional modules.

My test code is shown below.

The database name is `CSM`

Stored Procedure:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      <Author,,Name>
-- Create date: <Create Date,,>
-- Description: <Description,,>
-- =============================================
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.DUMMY 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @carrierId VARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    INSERT INTO dbo.carrier (carrierId, test)
    VALUES (@carrierId, 'Success')
END
GO
```

Jython Script:

```
from com.ziclix.python.sql import zxJDBC

conn = None
try :
    conn = zxJDBC.connect('jdbc:sqlserver://localhost\SQLEXPRESS', 'sa', 'password', 'com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver')
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.callproc(('CSM','dbo','DUMMY'), ['carrier1'])
    conn.commit()
except Exception, err :
    print err
    if conn:
        conn.rollback()
finally :
    if conn :
        conn.close()
```

By using `cur.execute()` I have been able to verify that the above is successfully connecting to the database, and that I can query against it. However, I have thus far been unable to successfully call a stored procedure with parameters.

The documentation [here](http://www.jython.org/archive/21/docs/zxjdbc.html)(possibly out of date?) indicates that `callproc()` can be called with either a string or a tuple to identify the procedure. The example given -

```
c.callproc(("northwind", "dbo", "SalesByCategory"), ["Seafood", "1998"], maxrows=2)
```

When I attempt to use this method, I receive the following error

```
Error("Could not find stored procedure 'CSM.DUMMY'. [SQLCode: 2812], [SQLState: S00062]",)
```

It would appear that zxJDBC is neglecting to include the `dbo` part of the procedure identifier.

If I instead call `callproc` with "CSM.dbo.DUMMY" as the first argument then I receive this error

```
Error('An object or column name is missing or empty. For SELECT INTO statements, verify each column has a name. For other statements, look for empty alias names. Aliases defined as "" or [] are not allowed. Change the alias to a valid name. [SQLCode: 1038], [SQLState: S0004]',)
```

Using a profiler on the database whilst running my script shows that in the second case the following SQL is executed:

```
use []
go
```

So it would seem that when using a single string to identify the procedure, the database name is not correctly parsed out.

One of my trial and error attempts to fix this was to call callproc as follows:

```
cur.callproc(('CSM', '', 'dbo.DUMMY'), ['carrier1'])
```

This got me only as far as

```
Error("Procedure or function 'DUMMY' expects parameter '@carrierId', which was not supplied. [SQLCode: 201], [SQLState: S0004]",)
```

In this case what I *think* is happening is that zxJDBC attempts to call a system stored procedure (`sp_proc_columns`) to determine the required parameters for the stored procedure I want to call. My guess is that with the procedure identifier in the incorrect format above, zxJDBC does not get a valid/correct return and assumes no parameters are required.

So basically I am not a bit stuck for ideas as to how to get it to

- Use the correct database name
- Correctly determine the required parameters using sp_proc_columns
- Call my stored procedure with the correct name

all at the same time.

I do have a workaround, which is to use something like

```
cur.execute('EXEC CSM.dbo.DUMMY ?', ['carrier1'])
```

However I feel like `callproc()` is the correct solution, and would likely produce cleaner code when I come to call stored procedures with large numbers of parameters.

If anyone can spot the mistake(s) that I am making, or knows that this is not ever going to work as I think then any input would be much appreciated.

Thanks

**Edit**

As suggested by i-one, I tried adding `cur.execute('USE CSM')` before calling my stored procedure (also removing the database name from the procedure call). This unfortunately produces the same Object or Column missing error as above. The profiler shows `USE CSM` being executed, followed by `USE []` so it seems that callproc() always fires a `USE` statement before the procedure itself.

I have also experimented with turning on/off autocommit, to no avail.

**Edit 2**

Further information following comments/suggested solutions:

- "SQLEXPRESS" in my connection string is the database instance name.
- Using double quotes instead of single has no effect.
- Including the database name in the connection string (via `;databaseName=CSM;` as specified [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378428%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)) and omitting it from the callproc() call leads to the original error with  a `USE []` statement being fired.

Using `callproc(('CSM', 'dbo', 'dbo.DUMMY'), ['carrier1'])` gives me some progress but results in the error

Error("Procedure or function 'DUMMY' expects parameter '@carrierId', which was not supplied. [SQLCode: 201], [SQLState: S0004]",)

I'll attempt to investigate this further

**Edit 3**

Based on the queries I could see zxJDBC firing, I manually executed the following against my database:

```
use CSM
go
exec sp_sproc_columns_100 N'dbo.DUMMY',N'dbo',N'CSM',NULL,N'3'
go
```

This gave me an empty results set, which would seem to explain why zxJDBC isn't passing any parameters to the stored procedure - it doesn't think it needs to. I have yet to figure out why this is happening though.

**Edit 4**

To update the above, the empty result set is because the call should be

```
exec sp_sproc_columns_100 N'DUMMY',N'dbo',N'CSM',NULL,N'3'
```

This unfortunately brings me full circle as I can't remove the `dbo` owner from the stored procedure name in my callproc() call or the procedure won't be found at all.

**Edit 5**

Table definition as requested

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[carrier](
    [carrierId] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [test] [varchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: Actually I'm not experienced to answer, I just see that bounty time is going out and you are alone with your problem. One thing I noticed in zxjdbc docs. Could you try following? After you initiated cursor (after `cur = conn.cursor()`) try `c.execute("use CSM")` (this should switch context from `master` database to `CSM` and allow referencing db objects without db name prefix) and then try `cur.callproc("dbo.DUMMY",["carrier1"])` or even `cur.callproc("DUMMY",["carrier1"])`. What happen if you do that?

Comment: @i-one Thanks for the suggestion. I didn't have any luck with it I'm afraid but have edited the question with a description of the result

Comment: May be `cur.callproc(('CSM', '', 'dbo.DUMMY ?'), ['carrier1'])` or `cur.callproc(('CSM', '', 'dbo.DUMMY @carrierId'), ['carrier1'])` ?

Comment: Those seem to confuse the call to `sp_proc_columns` as it thinks the parameters are part of the stored procedure name

Comment: Oh, it's a pity. But at least you have workable workaround.

Comment: What is `SQLEXPRESS` in the jdbc url (`jdbc:sqlserver://localhost\SQLEXPRESS`)?

Comment: 1. Have you tried to change single quotes to double quotes as per documentation example? 2. Have you tried to test in with a) stored procedure with no parameters, b) stored procedure without SELECT instead of INSERT?

Comment: @PavelNefyodov
1. See edit above
2a. This works fine
2b. This only works without parameters

Comment: Have you noticed that original [Northwind].[dbo].[SalesByCategory] has no INSERT in it? Try to copy Northwind.

Comment: My final verdict is - callproc approach is fundamentally flawed. Use this instead: cur.execute("exec CSM.dbo.DUMMY @Param1='" + str(Param1) + "', @carrierId=" + str(carrierID))

Comment: @PavelNefyodov That does seem to be the case, I just downloaded a copy of the northwind database and hit exactly the same problems with the example from the user guide. Guess I'll have to still with using execute()

Comment: Vindicare, I noted you were able to execute your proc with the 'dbo' owner, but an error occured in the INSERT statement. Can you pass me/public the table "Carrier" schema? Maybe you're just having a problem with the insert, and not with the Jython script...

Another thing: you are able to execute the procedure directly in SQL Server successfully?

Comment: @tcbrazil Updated the question to include the table definition. I think the question makes it clear that the error is in calling the stored procedure, not in the contents of the procedure. Yes I am able to call it from within SQL Server Management Studio where it works as expected.

Comment: Just a suggestion: Could you please try cur.callproc(('CSM', '', 'dbo.DUMMY'), 'carrier1')  (no square brackets for a parameter) as API Spec 2.0 suggests?

Comment: @PavelNefyodov That made no difference I'm afraid

Comment: Could you please check the same with original 'Northwind' example?

Comment: @PavelNefyodov Still getting the same errors there

Comment: Please note that 'Northwind' is SQL Server 2000 database and I suspect that example was working with SQL Server 2000. You use SQL Server 2008. Note: Database ownership feature has changed in SQL Server 2005. That may explain why 'dbo.Dummy' does not work.

Answer (score 3):

Though completely unaware of the technologies used here (unless some minor knowledge of SQL Server), I will attempt an answer (please forgive me if my jython syntax is not correct. I am trying to outline possibilities here not exact code)

My first approach (found at [this post](http://topgrin.typepad.com/all_in_a_days_work_/2006/03/jython_with_sq.html)) would be to try:

```
cur.execute("use CSM")
cur.callproc(("CSM","dbo","dbo.DUMMY"), ["carrier1"])
```

This must have to do with the fact that `sa` users always have the `dbo` as a default schema (described at [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3806245/sql-server-schema-and-default-schema))

If the above does not work I would also try to use the `CSM` database name in the JDBC url (this is very common when using JDBC for other databases) and then simply call one of the two below.

```
cur.callproc("DUMMY", ["carrier1"])
cur.callproc("dbo.DUMMY", ["carrier1"])
```

I hope this helps

**Update:** I quote the relevant part of the link that you can't view

```
>> Program calls a Stored Procedure - master.dbo.xp_fixeddrives on  MS SQL Server

from com.ziclix.python.sql import zxJDBC

def getConnection():
    url = "${DBServer.Url}"
    user= "${DBServer.User}"
    password = "${DBServer.Password}"
    driver = "${DBServer.Driver}"
    con = zxJDBC.connect(url, user, password, driver)
    return con

try:
    conn = getConnection()
    print 'Connection successful'
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("use master")
    cur.callproc(("master", "dbo", "dbo.xp_fixeddrives"))
    print cur.description
    for a in cur.fetchall():
        print a
finally:
    cur.close()
    conn.close()
    print 'Connection closed'
```

The error you get when you specified the call function like above suggests that the parameter is not passed correctly. So please modify your stored procedure to take a default value and try to call with passing `params = [None]`. If you see that the call succeeds we must have done something right as far as specifying the database is concerned.
Btw: the [most recent documentation](http://wiki.python.org/jython/UserGuide#sql-server) suggests that you should be able to access it with your syntax.

Comment: I've updated the question with the result of trying these suggestions. The first approach gave me some progress, though unfortunately I am unable to view the related link due to filters at work

Comment: If you see my edits 3 and 4 above, I'm pretty sure that the issue is with the 'dbo' side of things. Connecting to the database is fine, but when using a tuple to specify the stored procedure name, the middle element (dbo) seems to be ignored. Adding this to the last element will work only in the situation where the stored procedure has no parameters, as dbo.procName is not the correct procedure name so the required parameters are not determined by sp_sproc_columns

Comment: @Vindicare yes I think you are correct. That means that your driver has a flaw probably. [Another example](http://www.coderanch.com/t/566155/Jython-Python/MSSQL-stored-procedure-parameters-working) that looks like yours and the user decided to use `cursor.execute()` at the end.

Comment: I'm going to award the bounty here though not accept the answer, as although the problem isn't solved the suggestions were helpful and showed an understanding of the issue.

Answer (score 3):

As outlined in comments *callproc* will work only with SELECT. Try this approach instead:

```
cur.execute("exec CSM.dbo.DUMMY @Param1='" + str(Param1) + "', @carrierId=" + str(carrierID))
```

Please see [this link](http://www.coderanch.com/t/566155/Jython-Python/MSSQL-stored-procedure-parameters-working) for more detail.

Comment: I had stumbled across that link, which is part of what led me to the workaround mentioned in my question. However it says nothing about the problem being SELECT vs INSERT, and i believe my investigation shows this not to be the problem. Additionally, the documentation [here](http://www.jython.org/jythonbook/en/1.0/DatabasesAndJython.html#prepared-statements) recommends not using string concatenation to construct queries, but prepared statements (as per my example workaround)