# Create view can't find object name of table on another database

Tags: sql, sql-server, view, sql-server-2008-r2, schema

I have 2 SQLServer 2008 R2 databases. One database (A) has a table Foo in the testing schema. I am trying to create a view on the database (B) that references A.testing.Foo. However, I get an error when doing so. Here's the query (executed when logged into database B)

```
-- fails with Invalid object name 'A..Foo'
CREATE VIEW testing.Bar
AS
(SELECT * FROM A..Foo)

-- however, this succeeds when issued in the same context (same SSMS tab)
SELECT * FROM A..Foo

-- also, on both A and B
SELECT SCHEMA_NAME() -- returns 'testing'

-- also, this works
CREATE VIEW testing.Bar
AS
(SELECT * FROM A.testing.Foo)
```

Weirdly, this works on other pairs of databases, just not with A and B. Thus, I assume there must be some configuration issue, but I have no idea where to look! What could cause this behavior.

Comment: It could be because the default schema is dbo on A.  Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3806245/sql-server-schema-and-default-schema

Comment: What error are you receiving?

Answer (score 0):

Could be a naming collision as someone already said, but I would recommend using 3 part names when you start crossing DB boundaries (just for clarity)

```
ex: [Database].[schema].[tableName]
```

That way the person behind you, or you 2 weeks later, know what's going on. If you are crossing DB Server boundaries (slower and adds a whole new level of complexity) just do a linked server with a 4 part name

```
ex: [LinkedServerName].[Database].[schema].[tableName]
```