# SQL Server 2008 R2 Debug with user

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I need to figure out a way to run under debug in SQL Server Management Studio 2008 R2. But I am given some restrictions that I cannot find the workaround for:

- The user needs to be owner of a specific schema.
- For that reason, the user cannot have the SysAdmin privilege. The reason for this is we already have many Stored Procedures where we do not specify the name of the Schema for the SQL Queries.
- Since the user needs to have SysAdmin privilege, this conflicts with the first requirement as you cannot modify the DEFAULT_SCHEMA for sysadmins.

As far as I know, the only way to debug in SQL Server 2008 is to be given a SysAdmin privilege as this is how M$FT designed their software. What could be a possible workaround for this?

I understand that the recommended answer would be somewhere along the line of change how we wrote the SP or to consider redesigning the database design but sadly, this is not an option.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

By *run under debug* do you mean you want to debig stored procedures interactively using the T-SQL debugger?

If you are having problems getting this running, and your objective is to debug your code, you could also use SQL Profiler to observe exactly what is being executed inside your stored procedure. It of course will not support break points and start/stop but it will let you observe what is being executed.

Comment: Yeah I need to get the debug functionality to work, so this is not an option unfortunately D:

Comment: Sorry - I can't help any further. All indications are that you simply cannot do what you need to do. You could try hacking the security and explicitly granting your user access to the various objects required. It appears that you need to start at mssqlsystemresource.sys.sp_enable_sql_debug, but that would be a  hack and you spend days on it and not get a result.

Comment: Yeah I have no choice. I absolutely have to get this to work. I will try that.

Comment: But if it's not technically possible then there's not much you can do! good luck anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Taken from [MSDN: Run the Transact-SQL Debugger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878060.aspx)

> We recommend that Transact-SQL code be debugged on a test server, not
>   a production server, for the following reasons: Debugging is a highly
>   privileged operation. Therefore, only members of the sysadmin fixed
>   server role are allowed to debug in SQL Server. Debugging sessions
>   often run for long periods of time while you investigate the
>   operations of several Transact-SQL statements. Locks, such as update
>   locks, that are acquired by the session might be held for extended
>   periods, until the session is ended or the transaction committed or
>   rolled back.

If you have concerns you may want to report your wish at microsoft connect site:
http://connect.microsoft.com/sqlserver

Comment: Yeah I've seen that but unfortunately, I really need the debug functionality to work somehow or someway. The dilemma is that I need to have SysAdmin privilege in order to debug and if I give the SysAdmin privilege, I cannot set a default schema for the user. I'm just trying to circumvent this issue somehow.

Comment: Like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3292633/in-sql-server-2005-is-there-a-way-to-set-the-default-schema-to-anything-other-th ?  Its not possible, by design. I'm guessing there is another bigger problem that you're trying to solve and debugging will make it easier. Perhaps raise another [so] Question that details the root cause your trying to solve, you may get an answer without even needing a debugger. Good luck!

Comment: Nah, this is just a task that was given by my boss. "Find a way to make the debugger work under these circumstances", which I was pretty much like wtf to.

Comment: I know the type of boss, you'll have to somehow communicate with him/her that its not possible according to official documentation. **MSDN: Run the Transact-SQL Debugger** with the quote: `Debugging is a highly privileged operation. Therefore, only members of the sysadmin fixed server role are allowed to debug in SQL Server.` - that still doesn't answer my point about solving the bigger problem, or is this a wish list of impossible stuff your boss has? l46kok go find me the Sky Hooks, there in the freezer next to the elbow grease.

Comment: If I go off on a tangent here too much, this will probably be a thread appropriate for WorkPlace Beta so I can't say too much.. but yeah this is probably that wishlist you speak of. lol at the skyhooks though